# How to change the version requested from QGIS Plugin Repository?

Tags: qgis-2

I built QGIS from GitHub master branch (at about version 2.14.3) and am running from the build directory but it seems to be hardcoded to connect the the plugin repository sending a version of 1.19:

[image]

You don't seem to be able to edit this parameter.  Where does this value come from and how can I change it to fetch version 2 plugins?